# Is anybody aware why Firefox scrollbar colors are not applied? Tried latest version of firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I have tried applying styles to the scrollbar namely

```
scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
```

But nothing is showing up differently. I even tried the [official examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) from the Mozilla website and they don't work. They all look the same.

I am using mac v10.15.6

Comment: Have you set the System Preference?

Comment: i have no clue what you are referring to, can u enlighten me please?

Comment: I don't have much clue either, and I don't have a Mac so can't try this, but in [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-color they state 'On macOS, you need to set the <em>General</em> > <em>Show scroll bars</em> setting in System Preferences to "Always" for this property to have any effect.' I don't know whether it might work on Windows. scrollbar-color isn't supported in other browsers it seems.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, i wanted to style it for everybody but if its going to only show sometimes then i guess nvm, thanks for the info